# Syntax error in conversion for printing input file

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

i want to print my input file data to textbox but it shows error here is code

```
 private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.WriteAllLines(file1, richTextBox1.Text);  // file1 is my input file

    }
```

errors are:

```
// Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string'
// Error 4 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'
```

So my question is that how to convert list to string and string to `IEnumerable<string>`?

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            fdlg.Title = ".cs File Detector";
            fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
            fdlg.Filter = "cs files (*.cs)|*.cs";
            fdlg.FilterIndex = 2;
            fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = fdlg.FileName;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception eee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(eee.ToString());
        }

    }
```

I am calling file from here so now shall do the same thing to readtext for text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to read, not write:

```
richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: no its not working i want that whatever i choose a file its input data would be written in this textbox

Comment: @Rdx: I just test this and it works exactly like you want. I suspect the issue is that your file1 does not contain a complete file name. When I tested it, I entered c:\test.txt (an existing file) in the textbox and it loaded the RTB correctly. Can you edit your question to show how you set file1?

Comment: but i choose file on run time by selecting file that code is ok i browse and select files and it works but now i also want that whatever i choose it would come in this textbox...

Comment: Right, but if file1 only contains a filename (i.e. test.txt) and not the full path to the file (i.e. c:\documents\test.txt), ReadAllText will not be able to find the file.

Comment: It show conversion error that list<string> cant convert into string

Comment: @ competent_tech , i am calling file here i edit so now should i again call that inputfile????????????????

Comment: What type of control or property is file1?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5897/discussion-between-rdx-and-competent-tech)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use [`WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) instead?

Comment: no its not working i want that whatever i choose a file its input data would be written in this textbox..